# How to pass Arraylist<bean> from oneactivity to another activity in android

Tags: android, list, android-activity, android-listview, arraylist

I tried with intent of  intent.putExtra("listname", list) and shared preferance list.But it doesnot give the actual result. Help me out of this

Intent intent=new Intent(HotelSearch.this, HotelSearchResults.class); intent.putExtra("listname", list);

secondactivity:

hotelsearchresult=(ArrayList)intent.getSerializableExtra("listname");

Comment: You need to be much more specific.  What is happening, what did you expect to happen, is any error found in logcat, and post the exact code being used.

Answer (score 0):

You must use serializable model

```
intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);  
getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```

Your model will be like this;

```
public class City implements Serializable {

public String Name;
public String Name_EN;
public int ID;
}
```

for more answer follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736612/3098590